# Getting null is not an object error even though console log shows the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, lodash

I'm getting null is not an object for (val.uid) in the fetchNickname function, even though the console log shows the value of it correctly

```
if(this.props.user){
            _.map(this.props.user, (val) =>{
                console.log(val.uid)
                this.props.fetchNickname(val.uid)
            })
            setTimeout(() =>{
                this.props.info.map((one) =>{
                    this.setState({name: one.Nickname})
                })
            }, 1000)
        }
        setTimeout(() =>{
            this.setState({loaded: true})
        }, 1500)
```

Comment: because this is happening asynchronously

Comment: ok... How can i fix it?

Comment: by using promises => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises